# Returntype any instead of unknown for untyped reducers

Tags: typescript, redux

I am in the middle of a refactoring-process of a large redux state, my issue is that the reducers that has yet to be converted to typescript returns `unknown`, and I would rather want it to return `any`. Is there any way to change the default fallback of `ReturnType`?

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import pageReducer from './page';

const rootReducer = history =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    page: pageReducer,
    ....
    ....
  });

export type AppState = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>>
```

typings for combineReducers:

```
export function combineReducers<S>(
  reducers: ReducersMapObject<S, any>
): Reducer<S>
export function combineReducers<S, A extends Action = AnyAction>(
  reducers: ReducersMapObject<S, A>
): Reducer<S, A>
```

Comment: It seems that if there was a way to implement a conditional type called `UnknownToAny`, that returns any if unknown is passed or just return the passed in argument, this could solve your problem. But I can't think of a way to do it because anything is assignable to unknown...

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question doesn't seem to be a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or at least I can't get it to compile with my limited knowledge of redux) so forgive me if the following doesn't solve your problem.  Assuming @JuanMendes's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083987/returntype-any-instead-of-unknown-for-untyped-reducers#comment106267016_60083987) is the right suggestion, here's how one might write `UnknownToAny`:

```
type UnknownToAny<T> = unknown extends T ? any : T;
```

And therefore you can make your own `ReturnType` that outputs `any` instead of `unknown`:

```
type MyReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = UnknownToAny<ReturnType<T>>;
```

Let's test it:

```
function returnsNumber() { return 1; }
type N = MyReturnType<typeof returnsNumber>; // number

function returnsUnknown() { return 2 as unknown; }
type U = MyReturnType<typeof returnsUnknown>; // any

function returnsAny() { return 3 as any; }
type A = MyReturnType<typeof returnsAny>; // any
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps you; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wCrIIJxAHgwD4oBeKAV0RXSggA9gI4ATAZygygH4oBDPFABcnANwAoUJCgBZEACUIwCgCdM4CITqNm7KAAoAdMb4qA5mxECQASjIlrJcvCRpMOPPkXK1GDYSIiCXEAMyoAY2AAS2Q4KBUlVTg2ADkKAFsAIwgVfTsAb3jEtSgARlEoAF9JDSgUslkFYvVIfCkIZBCin2S0rJygqAB6Iag4DOyVcVCI6NjupLYXGjg8qEKEnqgAJn4OKld0Cur22Aa5byS-VvbOhbUl6jdBkf48abC4SJi4zcXcEBrDbNKAAZj2bxAxxq0mw5yaPWumluXT+DwBL1G1igQA)